# Least privileges required to put public-read objects on AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I created a new AWS IAM role, and gave it the following policy (trying to follow the principle of least privilege):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1493050925000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::avatars-bus-com-development/avatar/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Using `s3cmd`, I attempt to upload a publicly readable file using the following command line:

```
s3cmd put --public-acl --access_key AKIA... --secret_key "..." \
  spec/fixtures/avatars/large-avatar.jpg \
  s3://avatars-bus-com-development/avatar/00-55/inbb7ljt-2017-02-17-09-00-55/original.jpg
```

When I do that, I receive an Access Denied error from S3.

Using the AWS CLI tools, I also get an AccessDenied error:

```
$ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="AKIA..." AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="..." aws s3 cp \
    --acl public-read \
    --content-type image/png \
    spec/fixtures/image.png \
    s3://bus-com-avatars-development/avatar/francois.png
upload failed: spec/fixtures/image.png to s3://bus-com-avatars-development/avatar/francois.png An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

What other actions must be provided in order to put publicly readable objects on S3?

Comment: That should work. Can you try it with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I updated with the results of the AWS CLI. No change in behaviour: still getting an AccessDenied error.

Comment: BTW, you said you put the policy on an IAM Role, but you are using credentials so I'll assume you either put the policy on an IAM User or assumed the role to obtain credentials.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I meant that I assigned the policy directly to the user, no roles here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is being caused by `--acl public-read`, which requires `PutObjectAcl` permissions. (If you take that out, it works fine.)

Therefore, update your policy to this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::avatars-bus-com-development/avatar/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```